# Use a specific outbound IP with Docker

Tags: networking, debian, docker

I have 3 network interfaces: `docker0`, `eth0` and `eth0:0` (alias).

```
    auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
      address 1.2.3.4
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 1.2.3.0
      broadcast 1.2.3.255
      gateway 1.2.3.254

    auto eth0:0
      iface eth0:0 inet static
      address 5.6.7.8
      netmask 255.255.255.255
      broadcast 5.6.7.8
```

`docker0` is the bridge auto created by docker.

What's the easiest way to make Docker and all its containers use the outbound IP 5.6.7.8 instead of 1.2.3.4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears there is no easy way to do it with docker - at the moment at least.

What I ended up doing is simply using SNAT:

```
 iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 5.6.7.8
```

*`172.17.0.0/16` is the subnet used by `docker0`.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the --ip command line parameter.

```
# echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --ip=5.6.7.8"' >> /etc/default/docker
# docker help
...
  --ip=0.0.0.0     Default IP address to use when binding container ports
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. The public IP used by docker containers is still the same.

Comment: Does setting the outbound IP for a single container work? Try something like `docker run -i -t -p 5.6.7.8:12345:12345 ubuntu /bin/bash`

Comment: Outbound IP is still the same.

Comment: Which docker version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Docker 1.6.0