# Geting docker to use secondary IP (specify which IP docker uses)

Tags: docker

I have 2 IPs on my server.  The main one and an additional one.

```
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 111.222.204.107/22 brd 213.171.207.255 scope global enp7s0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 111.222.205.143/22 brd 213.171.207.255 scope global secondary enp7s0:0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe43:92df/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(ive changed the first two parts of the IP for security)

Currently, docker is using the main IP (111.222.204.107 / enp7s0) but I would like it to use the secondary one (111.222.205.143/enp7s0:0).

How best to achieve this.  Changing it 'globally' for docker would be great but if I could create docker network and specify the IP for this that would be fine.  A third least good option would be to set the IP in docker-compose but would rather do it globaly or for a network.

By 'docker uses' I mean accepts traffic coming from/and sends traffic to the primary IP.

It would be also good to get advice on how to set up IP tables when I do this but I can cross that bridge when I get to it.

I've been struggling with this one for a few days.

Comment: Thanks, also found a simpler solution using iptables/SNAT - https://serverfault.com/questions/686035/use-a-specific-outbound-ip-with-docker/686107#686107.  I like its simplicity or am I missing something.

Comment: OK, still stuck (for 5 days).  The server uses firewalld but all these solutions user iptables) the first seems to imply docker only works with tables.

Comment: I just tried 'firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -d 172.17.0.1/16 -p all -j SNAT --to 111.222.205.143' but it did not work.  I still get 'Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'